# Iphone 3G Games

Tags: iphone

I play Tap ranch which at times gives free points for downloading free apps. I've downloaded all free apps and have deleted them but when I try to download it again I dont get the free points. Is there a way to delete the memory of already downloaded games so I can receive the free points again. Thanks for helping.

Comment: It's not really clear what you've done and what you're trying to do.  Could you explain this in more detail for people who aren't familiar with "Tap ranch"?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is the device UDID is being sent in to the servers for each game.

[image: UDID]

Just click on the serial number in iTunes to reveal your UDID.

They see that your device showed up as a first launch of that game, so they don't actually know that you bought the app today and downloaded it. For privacy reasons, Apple has severely restricted how apps talk between themselves on your phone, so it's far more likely they are doing the matching and tracking on their game servers. (plus+, open feint, etc...)

- They know that you were playing game
  A today when they announced offer B.
- They do know you ran game B for the
  first time ever today (and maybe care it ran after A or maybe it's a specific version of game B).
- They grant you imaginary goods in game A to
  reward you for hitting their game B server with the same device identifier as your game A account.

I believe you would have got the bonus if you coincidentally ran game B after game A - even if you didn't actually see the offer. You could test this by downloading the app on another device using your account and see if they can tell you or just your device.

Why don't you ask the company that made the games how they knew? They might just tell you.